# RAID 5 reassemble stating wrong homehost?

Tags: raid, mdadm

So I went from a degraded RAID, to a dissasembled RAID, to now trying to reassemble it. Im getting a weird message when trying to `--assemble` the RAID. I have 6 drives, so `/dev/sd[a-f]1`. When trying to assemble the raid, I am getting that `e` and `f` are misses out due to wrong homehost. I tried to search around but I cant find the correct solution to get the RAID 5 going again.

Comment: root@V-HTPC:~# mdadm --examine --scan
     ARRAY /dev/md/127 metadata=1.2                UUID=5644d75d:ebb22217:bc09d634:46483e6d name=V-HTPC:127
     ARRAY /dev/md/127 metadata=1.2      UUID=d3fb62dc:ce1fefe7:2c8e8618:b8994ae3 name=Devastator:127

Comment: So there are 2 Arrays?

Comment: You state that only "e and f are misses out due to wrong homehost". This is not possible - homehosts are recorded for complete arrays. Are you sure all of those six partitions are part of the same array? Provide the output of `mdadm --examine /dev/sda1` (for all devices).

Comment: @gertvdijk here is the output: http://pastebin.com/Rw6DDHDA

Comment: e and f do not show (local to host) as the other drives do

Comment: take that back, only e shows a diff name but that its there.

Comment: but the array UUID for both e and f are different

Comment: vpoola88: you can edit your comments, rather than adding one for every small update. If UUIDs are different, they're not the same array. Again: are you really sure they're part of the same array? It does not indicate this. Are you also on the right partition of the drive? They even have different given names "Devastator" and "127". Please share the whole story.

Comment: @gertvdijk The whole story is: I have had this RAID5 with 6 drives for a few months with all of my media and such. Im using it as our homeserver, and email server. I followed this guide to initially setup the raid: http://zackreed.me/articles/38-software-raid-5-in-debian-with-mdadm   After setting it up, things have been fine, until recentely when I noticed I would boot it up and it would give me a degraded RAID status. So then I did mdadm --detail and found out that /dev/sdb1 was somehow removed. I simply readded the drive, and in doing so experienced a bunch of errors that lead me to this.

Comment: @gertvdijk (ran out of characters)/ anyways, once I got sdb1 readded, sde1 was coming back as a faulty spare. I attempted to readd it before anythng, and somehow in doing so crashed the raid. Now I have 2 diff names and I honestly dont know why.

Answer (score 4):

As a safety feature the kernel will only allow automatic assembly of arrays it is part of the same host. This is checked by the metadata field 'homehost' on the array. If it does not match the current hostname, it will refuse to start.

To force the array to start on your new system, you have two options:

- Update the homehost metadata on the array to match your new hostname.

  Use the `--update=homehost` option for `mdadm` on *assembling* to update the field with the current hostname on each drive.
- Tell `mdadm` to use the hostname of the old system when scanning for arrays.

  Use the option `--hostname=myhostname` when working with `mdadm`.

  or, specify an `HOMEHOST=myhostname` entry in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`.

Comment: thanks getvdijk: so this is what I did and this is what I am getting back:

Comment: root@V-HTPC:~# mdadm --assemble /dev/md127 --update=homehost      /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1
     mdadm: cannot open device /dev/sde1: No such file or directory
     mdadm: /dev/sde1 has no superblock - assembly aborted

Comment: @vpoola88 You're having a completely different problem there. `sde1` seems not to be available.

Comment: How would I make it available? Also, can you post examples of commands for both scenarios that you have above? Thanks so much.

Comment: @vpoola88 The device isn't there. Software can't do magic about making hardware available. Make sure you point `mdadm` to the devices part of the array, or, make it scan your whole system and point it to only one of the disks. (see manpage of `mdadm` and option/examples about `--scan`)

Comment: so I definately see that /dev/sde1 isnt available when I am trying to create the array. In theory a RAID-6 allows for one missing drive, so wouldnt I be able to just reassemble or create an array using the 5 good drives? This way I can backup my data

Comment: So I am trying to do it like so: root@V-HTPC:~# mdadm --assemble /dev/md127 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sdf1
mdadm: superblock on /dev/sdf1 doesn't match others - assembly aborted; I'm assuming the superblock that doesnt match is because it is on a different hostname? So now what would I do to get /dev/sdf1 back on the same superblock? If I can do that, I would like to backup my data on the degraded array, and then I dont mind recreating the whole thing after figuring out what is wrong with sde1

Comment: Your question has become 10 times more complicated from the original. From the output of the command you seem to specify disks from two different arrays now. Additionally, I don't see any hostname option in your command.

Comment: ok, sorry about that. Im still new to this so Im probably not being clear with whats exactly happening. if anyone has any suggestions please let me know. I still get mdadm --examine --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/127 metadata=1.2 UUID=5644d75d:ebb22217:bc09d634:46483e6d name=V-HTPC:127
ARRAY /dev/md/Devastator metadata=1.2 UUID=d3fb62dc:ce1fefe7:2c8e8618:b8994ae3 name=V-HTPC:Devastator and want to know how to fix it.

Comment: What makes this confusing is when you --create /dev/md/blah, and if you don't specifically set homehost to <none> when rebooting, the hostname gets prepended to blah. The semantics should be simplified here, so we don't get a path that will automatically disappear after a reboot. Why not just make sure you get /dev/md/hostname:boot from the very beginning? Before reboot.

Comment: This problem can be circumvented by explicitly stating "any" as the homehost on array creation.